# Operator == not compatible with types string memory and string memory

Tags: solidity, solc, string, compiler, foundry

```
function hasRole(uint256 tokenId, string memory role) public view returns (bool) {
    string[] memory userRoles = tokenToRoles[tokenId];
    uint256 userRolesLength = userRoles.length;
    unchecked {
        for (uint256 i; i < userRolesLength; ++i) {
            // if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(userRoles[i])) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(role))) {
            //     return true;
            // }
            if (userRoles[i] == role) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The above function compares a  `string memory` from a `string[]` array that I've copied to memory from storage with a `string memory` that is passed in through the function parameters. You would think such a comparison would be possible, however I am getting the following error in Foundry from the Solidity Compiler (version 0.8.17)

```
Compiler run failed
error[2271]: TypeError: Operator == not compatible with types string memory and string memory.
  --> src/policy/VertexPolicyNFT.sol:50:21:
   |
50 |                 if (userRoles[i] == role) {
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

the lines commented out are a working solution (hashing the two values and comparing the hashes), but it seems excessive and would be cleaner and less gas intensive if we could find a way to compare the strings.

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract StringComparison {

    string public a = "test";

    //pass "test" to b
   function compareStrings(string memory b) public view returns (bool) {
    return (keccak256(abi.encodePacked((a))) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked((b))));
}
}
```

Comment: I have this solution already commented out in my post. This is not the solution I am looking for. wondering how to compare the strings directly without hashing.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you should post your state mapping and arrays, but the thing which i realized it that: `tokenToRoles` is a mapping or array which stored some strings, you get an index of it by `tokenId`, so When you defining `userRoles as element of`  tokenToRoles`you should set an string not an array of string like`string[]`  you trying to get one element of array ,which is an string and define it as a array of string , then try to get an element of your new array which is you defined.
You should get element of array this way:

```
string memory userRoles = tokenToRoles[tokenId];
```